# Есть задача на питоне, которую мне дали, я не могу ее решить

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Задача такова: Создать список, состоящий из кубов нечётных чисел от **0** до **1000**:
Вычислить сумму тех чисел из этого списка, сумма цифр которых делится нацело на **7**.

Например, число `19 ^ 3 = 6859` будем включать в сумму,
так как `6 + 8 + 5 + 9 = 28` – делится нацело на **7**. Внимание: использовать только арифметические операции!

К каждому элементу списка добавить **17** и заново вычислить сумму тех чисел из этого списка, сумма цифр которых делится нацело на **7**.
Внимание: новый список не создавать!!!

Проблема в том, что ответ должен быть таким: `17485588610`, `15392909930`.
Но у меня получается совсем другое. мой код такой:

```
list_for_home_work = []

for i in range(1001):
    list_for_home_work.append(i)

    for num in list_for_home_work:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            list_for_home_work.pop()

for i in range(len(list_for_home_work)):
    list_for_home_work[i] = list_for_home_work[i] ** 3

sum = 0
temporary_num = 0
exit_num = 0


for num_1 in list_for_home_work:
    temporary_list = list(str(num_1))
    print(temporary_list)

    for val_2 in temporary_list:
        temporary_num += int(val_2)
    print()
    if temporary_num % 7 == 0:
        sum += temporary_num


    exit_num += sum


    # Дальше добавляем 17

for i in range(len(list_for_home_work)):
    list_for_home_work[i] += 17

sum = 0
temporary_num = 0
exit_num = 0

for num in list_for_home_work:
    temporary_list = list(str(num))

    for val_2 in temporary_list:
        temporary_num += int(val_2)

    if temporary_num % 7 == 0:
        sum += temporary_num

    exit_num += sum
```

Я серьезно пятый час сижу над задачей, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Поставил + за попытку самому решить задачу!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

да вы просто наусложнялись выше крыше

> Создать список, состоящий из кубов нечётных чисел от 0 до 1000

не надо ничего удалять - просто идите с шагом в 1 начиная с 1

```
arr = [i**3 for i in range(1, 1001, 2)]
```

> Вычислить сумму тех чисел из этого списка, сумма цифр которых делится
> нацело на 7

способов решить это много, но самый короткий (Хотя и не самый быстрый - через строки)

1. превратить число в строку через `str()`
2. превратить строку в массив цифр
3. преобразовать цифры в числа
4. подсчитать сумму

   ```
    sum(map(int, str(value))
   ```

и все

**P.S.**

на счет использования строк я погорячился - ведь в задаче написано "только арифметическими действиями", поэтому вот такой код у меня получился:

```
def sum_digits(value):
    res = 0

    while value != 0:
        res += value % 10
        value //= 10

    return res


arr = [i**3 for i in range(1, 1001, 2)]

res1 = sum(filter(lambda num: sum_digits(num) % 7 == 0, arr))
res2 = sum(filter(lambda num: sum_digits(num + 17) % 7 == 0, arr))

print(res1)
print(res2)
```

**P.P.S.**

если же не сковываться некоторыми условиями задачи, то все ее решение можно записать так:

```
print(sum(filter(lambda j: sum(map(int, str(j))) % 7 == 0, [i**3 for i in range(1, 1001, 2)])))
print(sum(filter(lambda j: sum(map(int, str(j + 17))) % 7 == 0, [i**3 for i in range(1, 1001, 2)])))
```

Comment: А если без лямбды, то как?

Comment: @Август, без лямбда просто через `for ... if` - `res = 0 for i in arr: if sum_digits(num) % 7 == 0: res += i` - лямбда просто позволяют свернуть цикл в одну строчку и все